# Is there a software to reverse normal maps?

Tags: normal-map

Said software would combine normal map with low poly mesh and re-create the high poly that was used to create it.

Does this software exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a high poly model from a low poly model and a normal map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/how-do-i-make-a-high-poly-model-from-a-low-poly-model-and-a-normal-map)